# Rally : Backlog and Reopen Defects

Tags: rally

How to get backlog Defects with Priority, also the Reopen defects using ".Net REST API"?

---

I tried this, but 
request.Query = new Query("Iteration", Query.Operator.Equals, null).and(
    new Query("Release", Query.Operator.Equals, null));
is throwing NullReferenceException

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are trying to find out here. Can you clarify for me?

Answer (score 0):

There are some code examples here: http://developer.rallydev.com/help/rest-api-net

To get backlog defects including the priority field you will want to do something like this:

```
RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi("username", "password", "https://rally1.rallydev.com", "1.24");

Request request = new Request("defect");
request.Fetch = new List()
    {
        "Name",
        "Description",
        "FormattedID",
        "Priority"
    };
request.Query = new Query("Iteration", Query.Operator.Equals, null).and(
    new Query("Release", Query.Operator.Equals, null));

QueryResult queryResult = restApi.Query(request);
foreach(var result in queryResult.Results)
{
    //Process item
    string priority = result["Priority"];
}
```

To check for reopened defects you'll also need to fetch the Revisions and RevisionHistory and then check through each revision's description for a change to the state field.